# Cannot increment variable in React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning React and trying to call API for users using this component:

It works and I get users for page=1,

But, when I click on next button, the method next is triggered which should update page variable to '2' but it doesn't happen.

```
import React , {Component} from "react";
import Wrapper from "../components/Wrapper";
import axios from "axios";
import {User} from "../../classes/user";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";



class Users extends Component {
    state = {
        users: []
    }

    page = 1

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`users?page=${this.page}`)

        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
            users: response.data.data
        })
    }

    next = async () => {
        this.page++; // this never gets incremented
        await this.componentDidMount();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-no-wrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
                        <div className="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
                            <Link to={'users/create'} className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Add</Link>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="table-responsive">
                    <table className="table table-striped table-sm">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Email</th>
                            <th scope="col">Role</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.state.users.map(
                            (user: User) => {

                                return (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{user.id}</td>
                                        <td>{user.first_name} {user.last_name}</td>
                                        <td>{user.email}</td>
                                        <td>{user.role.name}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div className="btn-group mr-2">
                                                <a href="" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</a>
                                                <a href="" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Delete</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )

                            }
                        )}


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <nav>
                    <ul className="pagination">
                        <li className="page-item">
                            <a href="" className="page-link">Previous</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="page-item">
                            <a href="" className="page-link" onClick={this.next}>Next</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}


export default Users;
```

No matter what page is always equal to 1:

```
url: 'users?page=1' in console
```

Why page variabel never gets incremented?

Alternatively, as suggested :

```
state = {
        users: [],
        page: 1
    }

   

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`users?page=${this.state.page}`)

        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
            users: response.data.data
        })
    }

    next = async () => {
        //this.page++;
        this.setState({
            page: this.state.page + 1
        })
        await this.componentDidMount();
    }
```

Also do not update page either...

Comment: I think we can move `page` to the state as well

Comment: That isn't remotely how you do state management and rerendering in React. Please [read through the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the variable page inside the state object.

You can increment the variable page like that :

```
this.setState({ 
   page: this.state.page + 1 
 })
```

Comment: Not sure how you meant this to be implemented vis state. But I did put page in the state and added this method to url call and the next method. Still the same result. I always only get page=1

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're missing is **State** concept as @devcarme mentioned. Particularly, you need to store *page counter* as a **State**, not as a **variable**.

I will oversimplify for learning purpose:

- Before React, when you click *Next page* button, you have to **reload the whole page** with a new URL. By only doing that, the page can have new content.
- React don't need to do that. React can "react" to that change by storing update in a **State**. With **State**, React can bring new content without reloading the whole page.

---

If you're not learn for **maintaining codebase**, I suggest you code in **Functional component** as it is shorter than **Class component** version, which make it's easier to approach.

In the long run, React dev team will focus on **Functional component** and keep **Class component** for legacy codebase. They will provide ways to update, for example **React Hooks**, which makes functional component mostly equivalent to class component.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use SyntheticEvent like this:

```
next = async (e:SyntheticEvent ) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.page++;
```

Now page gets incremented as I wanted.